# how to replace characters in a array quickly

Tags: c#, optimization

I am using a XML Text reader on a XML file that may contain characters that are invalid for the reader. My initial thought was to create my own version of the stream reader and clean out the bad characters but it is severely slowing down my program.

```
public class ClensingStream : StreamReader
{
        private static char[] badChars = { '\x00', '\x09', '\x0A', '\x10' };
    //snip
        public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
        {
            var tmp = base.Read(buffer, index, count);

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; ++i)
            {
                //check the element in the buffer to see if it is one of the bad characters.
                if(badChars.Contains(buffer[i]))
                    buffer[i] = ' ';
            }

            return tmp;
        }
}
```

according to my profiler the code is spending 88% of its time in `if(badChars.Contains(buffer[i]))` what is the correct way to do this so I am not causing horrible slowness?

Comment: what are you doing with `tmp` ?

Comment: What does 'badChars.Contains()' look like?

Comment: I think it would be better to see the total amount of time it requires rather than in comparison with everything else. Does it impose that much extra time?

Comment: @Tobias: I presume it's the LINQ implementation on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Note that you should loop up to `tmp`, not up to `buffer.Length`. The buffer only contains valid data up to the point indicated by `tmp`, so it's a waste of time to loop through the rest of the buffer.

Comment: @Guffa: But then the JIT can't eliminate bounds checking, so it probably doesn't make much difference.

Comment: +1 for optimising after profiling

Comment: @Ben Voight: That's correct, so the gain depends on how much of the buffer you don't have to process. Even if it would be slightly slower in some cases, it doesn't make much sense to process garbage data.

Comment: @Peter Of The Corn for a 400 mb file it was taking 35 seconds, after changing it to a hash set it went to 4 seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that it spends so much time in that line is because the `Contains` method loops through the array to look for the character.

Put the characters in a `HashSet<char>` instead:

```
private static HashSet<char> badChars =
  new HashSet<char>(new char[] { '\x00', '\x09', '\x0A', '\x10' });
```

The code to check if the set contains the character looks the same as when looking in the array, but it uses the hash code of the character to look for it instead of looping through all the items in the array.

Alternatively, you could put the characters in a switch, that way the compiler would create an efficient comparison:

```
switch (buffer[i]]) {
  case '\x00':
  case '\x09':
  case '\x0A':
  case '\x10': buffer[i] = ' '; break;
}
```

If you have more characters (five or six IIRC), the compiler will actually create a hash table to look up the cases, so that would be similar to using a `HashSet`.

Comment: I was busy writing the same thing. If you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, or rip System.Core out of Mono and recompile it for 2.0, HashSet<T> is the way to go due to the lookup complexity.

Comment: Changing it to a hash set changed the run time form 35 seconds to 4 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

You might have better results with a `switch` statement:

```
switch (buffer[i])
{
    case '\x00':
    case '\x09':
    case '\x0A':
    case '\x10':
        buffer[i] = ' ';
        break;
}
```

This should be compiled down to fast code by the JIT compiler at runtime. Heck, the compiler might get close too. You don't need a method call this way either.

Comment: If I had to time it, I would try a variant with an if (buffer[i] <= (char)0x10) around the switch, so 99% of the times it does only a single comparison (this if the switch isn't converted to an hashtable or similar)

Comment: Measured, 20% faster on release without debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) for that which should be optimized. Read the text into a string and use [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) with your characters in the regular expression afterwards.

However, your code also looks fine to me, I guess regex also can't do anything else than searching through your text... and you need to take a string there which you don't need to do with the other options.

Answer (score 0):

you could check how well it optimises with just checking the read chars, making it

```
for (int i = index; i < index + count; i++){
  //etc
}
```

Don't know if/how much this would help you, you'd have to profile your real world application to check

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the `char[]` to a string and then using `IndexOfAny`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a boolean array

```
char[] badChars = { '\x00', '\x09', '\x0A', '\x10' };
char maxChar = badChars.Max();
Debug.Assert(maxChar < 256);
bool[] badCharsTable = new bool[maxChar + 1];

Array.ForEach(badChars, ch => badCharsTable[ch] = true);
```

and replace `badChars.Contains(...)` with `(ch < badCharsTable.Length && badCharsTable[ch])`.

Edit: Finally had time to improve the answer.

Comment: This is going to have issues with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Yes, that is true. The example contained only ASCII characters so I assumed that this approach would be safe here.

Comment: this is very space inefficient. Hash table beats sparse arrays anytime.

Comment: @Kugel: That depends on the size.  The overhead of your hash table is probably as much as the whole table for ASCII lookup, and the lookup table is MUCH faster.  Remember that a hash table is a lookup table, just you're looking up hashes instead of values, and what you get is a pointer to a list of values with that hash, that you then have to search sequentially.  Pointers are much bigger than `bool`.

Comment: @mgronber: Using a small lookup table is safe.  Casting `(byte)ch` will give false-positives though.  Better to do a range check instead of masking off the high bytes.  e.g. `(ushort)ch <= 255 && badCharsTable[ch]`.  Obviously even more space can be saved using knowledge of the last bad character.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thank you for you comments. I wrote the original answer in a hurry and I forgot to check the value range before casting. Current implementation should compare pretty well against HashSet<> when the array is not too sparse.