# List.except on custom class

Tags: c#, linq

lets say I have a custom class:

```
public class WineCellar
{

    public string year;
    public string wine;
    public double nrbottles;
}
```

Lets say I now have a List of this custom class:

```
List<WineCellar> orignialwinecellar = List<WineCellar>();
```

containing these items:

```
2012 Chianti 12

2011 Chianti 6

2012 Chardonay 12

2011 Chardonay 6
```

I know that if I want to compare two list and return a new list that has only items that are not in the other list I would do:

```
var newlist = list1.Except(list2);
```

How can I extend this to a custom class? Lets say I have:

```
string[] exceptionwinelist = {"Chardonay", "Riesling"};
```

I would like this to be returned:

```
List<WineCellar> result = originalwinecellar.wine.Except(exceptionwinelist);
```

This pseudocode obviously doesnt work but hopefully illustrates what I m trying to do. This shoudl then return a List of the custom class winecellar with following items:

2012 Chianti 12

2011 Chianti 6

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't really want to use `Except` here, as you don't have a collection of `WineCellar` objects to use as a blacklist. What you have is a collection of rules: "I don't want objects with such and such wine names".

Therefore it's better to simply use `Where`:

```
List<WineCellar> result = originalwinecellar
    .Where(w => !exceptionwinelist.Contains(w.wine))
    .ToList();
```

In human-readable form:

> I want all WineCellars where the wine name is not present in the list of exceptions.

As an aside, the `WineCellar` class name is a bit misleading; those objects are not cellars, they are inventory items.

Comment: If you are doing this sort very frequently or the exception list contains many items you may want to store the exception list as a `HashSet<string>` to make the `Contains` function much faster. However, as always, benchmark both methods as `HashSet` does have a non negligible cost to create.

Comment: @Jon, nice one... I was thinking waayyy too far here... mind the cast to `List<WineCellar>`, though ;-)

Comment: @DarenThomas: Yup, I missed that -- fixed now.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That's true. I did not go that far because if this is going to end up being really processing-heavy then a straight `List` would also be a bad choice for the input data, so the result would not have much in common with the original question.

Comment: Every time I see a question using a `Contains` on an array [I get flashbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261858/how-to-replace-characters-in-a-array-quickly). I just want to help other people learn from my mistakes :)

Comment: @Jon +1 for pointing out the problem with the naming of `WineCellar` - this bugged me too!

Comment: Thanks! works fine. I agree naming is misleading => still lots to learn for me...:)

Answer (score 7):

One solution is with an extension method:

```
public static class WineCellarExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<WineCellar> Except(this List<WineCellar> cellar, IEnumerable<string> wines)
    {
        foreach (var wineCellar in cellar)
        {
            if (!wines.Contains(wineCellar.wine))
            {
                yield return wineCellar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
List<WineCellar> result = originalwinecellar.Except(exceptionwinelist).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice extension method! The only thing I would do different is change the first parameter to `this IEnumerable<WineCellar> cellar`

Comment: Using contains to List leads to VERY bad performance since Contains on List is O(n) operation and it is executed on every step. On this case it should be done through HashSet or Dictionary.

Comment: @gleb.kudr I know. *except*, that is a different quetsion (how to optimize this code that runs slow) and depends on the input. Sure. Go ahead and stash the `wines` parameter in a `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: The best way is to implement GetHashCode. That kind of 'this List<SpecyficType>' extensions messes up the core concept of generics where you have a general implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`exceptionWineList` is a `string[]` but `originalWineCellar` is a `List<WineCellar>`, `WineCellar` is not a `string`, so it does not make sense to perform an `Except` between these.

You could just as easily do,

```
// use HashSet for look up performance.
var exceptionWineSet = new HashSet<string>(exceptionWineList);
var result = orginalWineCellar.Where(w => !exceptionWineSet.Contains(w.Wine));
```

---

What I think you are alluding to in your question is something like

```
WineCellar : IEquatable<string>
{
    ...
    public bool Equals(string other)
    {
        return other.Equals(this.wine, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

which allows you to equate `WineCellar`s to `string`s.

---

However, if I were to rework your model I'd come up with something like,

```
enum WineColour
{
    Red,
    White,
    Rose
}

enum WineRegion
{
    Bordeaux,
    Rioja,
    Alsace,
    ...
}

enum GrapeVariety
{
    Cabernet Sauvignon,
    Merlot,
    Ugni Blanc,
    Carmenere,
    ...
}

class Wine
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Vineyard { get; set; }
    public WineColour Colour { get; set; }
    public WineRegion Region { get; set; }
    public GrapeVariety Variety { get; set; }
}

class WineBottle
{
    public Wine Contents { get; set; }
    public int Millilitres { get; set; }
    public int? vintage { get; set; }
}

class Bin : WineBottle
{
    int Number { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
}

class Cellar : ICollection<WineBottle> 
{
    ...
}
```

Then, you can see that there are several ways to compare `Wine` and I may want to filter a `Cellar` on one or more of `Wine`'s properties. Therefore I might be temtpted to give myself some flexibility,

```
class WineComparer : EqualityComparer<Wine>
{
    [Flags]
    public Enum WineComparison
    {
        Name = 1,
        Vineyard= 2,
        Colour = 4,
        Region = 8,
        Variety = 16,
        All = 31
    }

    private readonly WineComparison comparison;

    public WineComparer()
        : this WineComparer(WineComparison.All)
    {
    }

    public WineComparer(WineComparison comparison)
    {
        this.comparison = comparison;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Wine x, Wine y)
    {
        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Name) != 0
            && !x.Name.Equals(y.Name))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Vineyard) != 0
            && !x.Vineyard.Equals(y.Vineyard))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Region) != 0
            && !x.Region.Equals(y.Region))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Colour) != 0
            && !x.Colour.Equals(y.Colour))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Variety) != 0
            && !x.Variety.Equals(y.Variety))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetHashCode(Wine obj)
    {
        var code = 0;
        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Name) != 0)
        {
            code = obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Vineyard) != 0)
        {
            code = (code * 17) + obj.Vineyard.GetHashCode();
        }

        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Region) != 0)
        {
            code = (code * 17) + obj.Region.GetHashCode();
        }

        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Colour) != 0)
        {
            code = (code * 17) + obj.Colour.GetHashCode();
        }

        if ((this.comparison & WineComparison.Variety) != 0)
        {
            code = (code * 17) + obj.Variety.GetHashCode();
        }

        return code;
    }
}
```

this probably looks like a lot of effort but it has some use. Lets say we wanted all the wine except the Red Rioja in your cellar, you could do something like,

```
var comparison = new WineComparer(
    WineComparison.Colour + WineComparison.Region);

var exception = new Wine { Colour = WineColour.Red, Region = WineRegion.Rioja }; 

var allButRedRioja = cellar.Where(c => 
    !comparison.Equals(c.Wine, exception));
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue to. I tried the example from Darren but couldn't get that to work properly.

I therefore made a modification from Darren´s example as follows:

```
static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<Product> Except(this List<Product> x, List<Product> y)
    {
        foreach(var xi in x)
        {
            bool found = false;
            foreach (var yi in y) { if(xi.Name == yi.Name) { found = true; } }
            if(!found) { yield return xi; }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me. You can possibly add several fields in the if clause if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To directly use such extension methods with generic classes you should implement comparator. It consists of two methods: Equal and GetHashCode. You should implement them in your WineCellar class. 
[Note the second example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx).

Note that the hash-based methods are much faster than basic 'List.Contains...' implementations.

Comment: The ['IEqualityComparer<T>' interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).