# Inline HashSet<> declaration vs static attribute, .Contains() performance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, hashset

In order to use the Contains method, what is better (is any difference), declare a static fieldwith the HashSet or declare it inline (new HashSet { SomeEnum.SomeValue1, SomeEnum.SomeValue2, ... }.Contains(SomeEnum.SomeValue1))

I ask that because in some cases I only going mto use the hashset once, and for me is better to have it on the code and not in some static attribute

Example inline (What I wanna use):

```
public void Validate(Type type) {
    if(!new HashSet<Type> { Type.TYPE_1, Type.TYPE_2, Type.TYPE_3, Type.TYPE_4 }.Contains(type)) {
        //do something
    }
    if(new HashSet<Type> { Type.TYPE_2, Type.TYPE_3, Type.TYPE_4, Type.TYPE_5 }.Contains(type)) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Example static (What I prefer not to use):

```
private static HashSet<Type> _values1 = new HashSet<Type> { Type.TYPE_1, Type.TYPE_2, Type.TYPE_3, Type.TYPE_4 };
private static HashSet<Type> _values2 = new HashSet<Type> { Type.TYPE_2, Type.TYPE_3, Type.TYPE_4, Type.TYPE_5 };
public void Validate(Type type) {
    if(!_values1.Contains(type)) {
        //do something
    }
    if(_values2.Contains(type)) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Example using logical expressions (What I don't want to use):

```
public void Validate(Type type) {
    if(type != Type.TYPE_1 && type != Type.TYPE_2 && type != Type.TYPE_3 && type != Type.TYPE_4) {
        //do something
    }
    if(type == Type.TYPE_2 || type == Type.TYPE_3 || type == Type.TYPE_4 || type == Type.TYPE_5) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Once in the entire process, or once per call? It would really help if you'd give an example here.

Comment: Your code example please.. This is so vague.

Comment: Adding a local `HashSet` may impact performance, but adding a static attribute is much worse: it is going to kill re-enterability.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It sounds like it's just for a (not-modified) lookup.

Comment: I added some examples, thank you

Comment: @SebastiánRojasRicaurte: What you call "static attributes" are known in the C# world as "static fields." "Attributes" have a different meaning.

Comment: Why not just test it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have not identified this as a bottleneck through performance testing, the the "right" way is just to use code that makes the most sense to people reading it. That's somewhat subjective, so there may not be a "right" way, but any approach that's not easy to understand will be the "wrong" way.

I would probably just use an inline-declared array, unless the list of values is reusable in other methods, or it's so long that it gets in the way of reading what the method is trying to do.

```
public void Validate(Type type) {
    if(!new[] { Type.TYPE_1, Type.TYPE_2, Type.TYPE_3, Type.TYPE_4 }.Contains(type)) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

If you have identified this as a definite performance bottleneck (meaning you're probably doing this check millions of times per second, then you'll probably want to do performance testing on a few different approaches, because the correct answer depends on how many items are in the set you're trying to match against.

Besides the approaches you've suggested, here are a couple of other possibilities that will *probably* be faster (but again, you'd need to test them to make sure:

#### Flags Enum

It looks like you're using enum values. If that enum type has a small number of potential values, you could make it into a flags enum and then use bitwise logic to determine in a single CPU operation whether the given value matches any of the values you're looking for.

```
[Flags]
public enum Type
{
    TYPE_1 = 1,
    TYPE_2 = 1<<1,
    TYPE_3 = 1<<2,
    TYPE_4 = 1<<3,
    TYPE_5 = 1<<4,
    // etc...
}
```

Usage:

```
const Type toMatch = (Type.TYPE_1 | Type.TYPE_2 | Type.TYPE_3 | Type.TYPE_4);
if((type & toMatch) == 0)
{
    // do something
}
```

#### Switch statement

The compiler is really good at figuring out what will be the fastest approach, so if you use a switch statement it can decide whether to compile that to a series of if/else checks, a HashSet-style approach, or a jump table, depending on the number and values of items you're trying to check.

```
switch(type)
{
    case Type.TYPE_1:
    case Type.TYPE_2:
    case Type.TYPE_3:
    case Type.TYPE_4:
        break;
    default:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an excample of Flags Enum way?

Comment: @SebastiánRojasRicaurte: I was working on it. It's there now.

Comment: I see, but you can put what is equivalent to `const Type toMatch = (Type.TYPE_1 | Type.TYPE_2 | Type.TYPE_3 | Type.TYPE_4);
if((type & toMatch)` and the equivalents for `(type == Type.TYPE_3 || type == Type.TYPE_4)` and for `(type != Type.TYPE_3 && type != Type.TYPE_4)`

Comment: @SebastiánRojasRicaurte: I don't understand what you just said.

Comment: I just edited my question. Please see it, I need to know hot to achieve the two scenarios in each example (that received value is NOT in a list of values and received value is in an other list of values)

Comment: @SebastiánRojasRicaurte: I don't know if it's a good idea to change the question at this point--it's likely to confuse future visitors since the existing answers are all for the original question. You should easily be able to negate the existing examples. `type & toMatch` will be zero if it's not a match, and non-zero if it is a match.

Comment: Maybe, but I only add more examples. Thanks for your reply, thats what I wanna know

Answer (score 0):

If no new items are going to be added then your static method is the correct way to do it

```
private static HashSet<Type> _values = new HashSet<Type> { Type.TYPE_1, Type.TYPE_2, Type.TYPE_3, Type.TYPE_4 };
public void Validate(Type type) {
    if(!_values.Contains(type)) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

All collections in the `System.Collections` namespace are thread safe [for read only operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/573ths2x%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) so this is a perfectly acceptable way to do it.

If you did it your "preferred" way it would still work, however you would be re-creating the collection every time you call the function and that is a unnecessary overhead that would definitely hurt performance.

Comment: What about logical expressions way? My problem is that there are long classes and methods, and I wanna have the values tested for easy viewing inside the "if" condition

Comment: Logical expressions or switch statements would be even better than a HashSet. However you may be getting in to microoptimization territory. I would reccomend running a profiler like [StriplingWarrior suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19798508/80274) and see if this section is causing a slowdown in the first place, if it is not causing a slowdown just pick the one that is the most readable (which appears to be your preferred inline method from your OP).

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with the "infrequent" or "once" usage of the lookup in mind, as hinted by the post..

If the lookup is used only within the single method then I would use an inline approach, however I would us an *array* (and I actually do quite often). I may or may may not use an intermediate (local) variable, depending on if I it makes the code more clear or easy to adapt in the future.

I wouldn't use a static (or even instance) variable because:

1. The sequence is *not shared* in this case;
2. The of trivial amount of resources to create the object (especially for an array) is minimal;
3. The GC is really good with short-lived objects .. and, more importantly, there is *no need to extend the lifetime*

If I wanted to share this lookup across several methods, I would look into creating a getter that returned a *new* object (which covers #2 and #3 above while meeting the new requirement). With a local variable, individual methods would only create one new lookup per invocation.

I generally use an array because:

1. The syntax is marginally *simpler* (the type can be inferred and omitted);
2. The array (especially the construction) is more lightweight than a HashSet, yet provides the required lookup functionality;
3. Searching a small array is likely *fast enough* (as there is a very small n)

I would not use various long-hand forms if it makes the particular code harder to follow. The task is "contains", not some more complex conditional logic.

Unless there is an actual performance problem, do it a *clean and simple* way and move on with more interesting tasks.

Comment: Even with a small number of elements a inline array can be significantly slower than a HashSet if you are calling the function ***very*** frequently. I learned this [first hand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261858/how-to-replace-characters-in-a-array-quickly), switching from a `char[]` with 4 elements to a `HashSet<char>` with 4 elements changed my file processing time from 35 seconds to 4 seconds.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Indeed - performance benchmarks should be done of critical code. This answer is written with "infrequent" or "once" usage in mind. If I was optimizing for a specific scenario it may be entirely different.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That's an interesting observation. Part of that is because `.Contains` on an array is a LINQ method, which does some extra reflection to see if it can call a more optimized method on the `ICollection` interface. If you simply cast your array as an `IList`, performance improves by quite a bit. But it's still slower than `HashSet`, at least for `char` values. Neither approach is nearly as good as a simple series of `(c == 'a' || c == 'b' || ...` checks.