# How Can I Edit Bytes As They Pass Through A Stream?

Tags: c#, replace, stream, byte, edit

My goal is to have a file stream open up a user-chosen file, then, it should stream the files bytes through in chunks (buffers) of about 4mb (this can be changed it's just for fun). As the bytes travel (in chunks) through the stream, I'd like to have a looping if-statement see if the bytes value is contained in an array I have declared elsewhere. (The code below will build a random array for replacing bytes), and the replacement loop could just say something like the bottom for-loop. As you can see I'm fairly fluent in this language but for some reason the editing and rewriting of chunks as they are read from a file to a new one is eluding me. Thanks in advance!

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenNewKey();

        const int chunkSize = 4096; // read the file by chunks of 4KB
        using (var file = File.OpenRead(textBox1.Text))
        {
            int bytesRead;
            var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
            while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                byte[] newbytes = buffer;
                int index = 0;
                foreach (byte b in buffer)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++)
                    {
                        if (buffer[index] == Convert.ToByte(lst[x]))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                newbytes[index] = Convert.ToByte(lst[256 - x]);
                            }
                            catch (System.Exception ex)
                            {
                                //just to show why the error was thrown, but not really helpful..
                                MessageBox.Show(index + ", " + newbytes.Count().ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                AppendAllBytes(textBox1.Text + ".ENC", newbytes);
            }
        }
    }

    private void GenNewKey()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        while (lst.Count < 256)
        {
            int x = rnd.Next(0, 255);
            if (!lst.Contains(x))
            {
                lst.Add(x);
            }
        }

        foreach (int x in lst)
        {
            textBox2.Text += ", " + x.ToString();
            //just for me to see what was generated
        }
    }

    public static void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path + ".ENC"))
        {
            File.Create(path + ".ENC");
        }
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

Where textbox1 holds the path and name of file to encrypt, textBox2 holds the generated cipher for personal debugging purposes, button two is the encrypt button, and of course I am using System.IO.

Comment: You mean [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261858/how-to-replace-characters-in-a-array-quickly)?

Comment: Sort of, but it's the reading and writing that is my problem, because even though I have tried every way to close the writer stream to move on to the next chunk, it doesn't close. I think it has something to do with how I'm reading them but I am not sure.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create some kind of [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher), are you just doing this for fun or are you going to be relying on this to provide security for a project of yours? If it is for security note that people break substitution ciphers for fun every day in their [morning newspaper](http://www.cecildaily.com/diversions/cryptoquip/). With modern computing they provide very little security.

Comment: It's just for fun, now I have it working on files of a certain size and under, however now I get an Out Of Range exception. I will edit the question with my full code in a moment.

Comment: Which line does the error happen on?

Comment: Umm, `newbytes[index] = Convert.ToByte(lst[256 - x]);` But just as a note my numbers could be one off idk.

Comment: I just fixed that error! Now it just seems to freeze up...

Comment: It probably doesn't help that you obtain and release the file handle for the output file every time you append a chunk to it. A quick way to determine if this is the source of your performance problem is to increase the buffer size handsomely (e.g. to be at least as large as the input file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you have a off by one error in `newbytes[index] = Convert.ToByte(lst[256 - x])`

if `x` is 0 then you will have `lst[256]`, however `lst` only goes between 0-255. Change that to 255 should fix it.

The reason it freezes up is your program is EXTREMELY inefficient and working on the UI thread (and has a few more errors like you should only go up to `bytesRead` in size when processing `buffer`, but that will just give you extra data in your output that should not be there. Also you are reusing the same array for `buffer` and `newbytes` so your inner `for` loop could modify the same index more than once because every time you do `newbytes[index] = Convert.ToByte(lst[256 - x])` you are modifying `buffer[index]` which will get checked again the next itteration of the `for` loop).

There is a lot of ways you can improve your code, here is a snippet that does similar to what you are doing (I don't do the whole "find the index and use the opposite location", I just use the byte that is passed in *as the index in the array*).

```
while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    byte[] newbytes = new byte[bytesRead];
    for(int i = 0; i < newbytes.Length; i++)
    {
        newbytes[i] = (byte)lst[buffer[i]]))
    }
    AppendAllBytes(textBox1.Text + ".ENC", newbytes);
}
```

This may also lead to freezing but not as much, to solve the freeing you should put all of this code in to a `BackgroundWorker` or similar to run on another thread.

Comment: Will adding it to a bg worker make it run faster? What's a UI thread? and also, I'll have to keep playing with this tonight, however if it works I will let you know and mark this as the answer! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Run faster, no. But your program won't lock up while it is running. As for the UI thread, it is the thread that `Application.Run(new Form1())` is running inside of that makes your mouse clicks work. Do some google searches on UI Thread and C# and you will find many results.

Comment: Ok, so I've used your code and toyed with it a tiny bit, but it now just doesn't switch certain bytes, should I post that as a separate question?

Comment: Yes you should, feel free to ask a new question and include the code you did. (also mark this one accepted if you feel it "answered your question")

Comment: Thank you I'll post it if I keep having issues after I play with it a bit more.