# How can I not repeat the whole part of an OR in an if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have this:

```
if (button1.Text == "1" || button1.Text == "2" || button1.Text == "3" || button1.Text == "4")
```

How do I turn this into something like:

```
if (button.Text == "1" || "2" || "3" || 4")
```

so I don't have to re-type `button1.Text ==` every time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a `List<string>` and store all your values inside of it.

```
var numbers = new List<string>  { "1","2","3","4"};
```

Then use [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check whether the `button1.Text` is present in your list or not:

```
if(numbers.Contains(button1.Text))
```

Also you can use a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for better and faster lookup.But in this case, it seems unnecessary because it doesn't make any significant difference.

Comment: I don't understand why so many people are so taken with using collections.  A List<T> is intended to act as a dynamic array.  If you don't need the dynamism then just use an array, not a List<T>.  In this case, as literals were being used originally, use an array of literals.  You should be using an array unless you need the specific functionality that a a List<T> provides in excess of an array.  Remember, a List<T> uses an array internally so must be inherently less efficient.  `if (new[] {"1", "2", "3", "4"}.Contains(button1.Text))`

Comment: Since we all love one liners: `new []{"1","2", "3", "4"}.Contains(button1.Text)`.(of course you have to include System.Linq for that :) )

Comment: @jmcilhinney could you explain what makes that line is more efficient than `List<T>.Contains`

Comment: Per your `HashSet` comment, I would like to clarify. For *this* case it will not make a difference, however if you are doing a set of checks very frequently in a tight loop, it can make a very large difference. See [this old question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261858/how-to-replace-characters-in-a-array-quickly) where changing from a `char[].Contains(` to a `HashSet<char>.Contains(` changed my run time from 35 seconds to 4 seconds.

Comment: @Selman22, I already did, but let's go again. A List<T> is a wrapper for an array. How can using a wrapper ever be as efficient as using the object it wraps directly for the same functionality? A List<T> obviously provides extra functionality and you should absolutely use a List<T> if you need to use that extra functionality. If you're just using basic array functionality though, just use a basic array.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that is your **opinion** not a **rule**.if `List<T>` provides more and requires nothing more than array,then I choose using generic lists instead of arrays in most cases.

Comment: @Selman22, it's not my opinion. It's a fact that using an array is more efficient than using a List<T> for basic array functionality. The difference won't be perceptible to the user but that doesn't mean that you shouldn't still choose the more efficient option. There are very few actual rules in programming other than those enforced by the compiler but there is such a thing as "best practice". If there are two ways to do something and one is more efficient while the other offers no advantage then the choice should be obvious. Doesn't a DataTable offer more than a List<T>? Why not use that?

Answer (score 1):

Another option to do what you want, if you are using a set of hard coded fixed values, is use a [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement.

```
if (button1.Text == "1" || button1.Text == "2" || button1.Text == "3" || button1.Text == "4")
{
    //Some code
}
```

can be turned in to

```
switch(button1.Text)
{
    case "1":
    case "2":
    case "3":
    case "4":
        //Some code       
        break;
}
```

and it will be as fast (or faster as there is only one access to `button1.Text`) as your `||` statements chained together.